# jquery: $.post success handler does not take else {}

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me in this weird situation.
This is the first time I see, when else{} does not work after if(){}. =)))

```
onClick="$.post('itemupdate.php', { itemname: 'test' }, function(data) { if(data.status == 'error'){alert('error')} else {alert('OK')} }, 'json');"
```

Alert 'OK' never shows up. Everything else is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made an output called ok!

```
if (mysql_error()) { $return_arr["status"] = 'error'; } else { $return_arr["status"] = 'ok'; } echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

now things works!

```
function(data) { if(data.status == 'error'){alert('error')} if(data.status == 'ok') {alert('OK')} }
```

Answer (score 5):

> If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail
>   silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()
>   method or. As of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object
>   returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Also: if you want to access the request status, the callback function gets 3 parameters:
data, textStatus, jqXHR. If you return crappy json, your data is null or undefined, and data.status would fail ofc.

This is the correct code. Also, I suggest you do not ever put your code in html attributes!

```
$.post('itemupdate.php', 
    { itemname: 'test' }, 
    function(data, status) { 
        if (status == 'error') {
            alert('error');
        } 
        else {
            alert('OK');
        } 
    }, 
    'json'
);
```

Comment: In other words there's nothing wrong with the if/else statement, the problem is that the success callback is only called on...well...success...

Comment: Actually in my case - callback is called when data (script output) is not empty.

Comment: Just made an output called ok!

    if (mysql_error()) { $return_arr["status"] = 'error'; } else { $return_arr["status"] = 'ok'; }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

now things works!

    function(data) { if(data.status == 'error'){alert('error')} if(data.status == 'ok') {alert('OK')} }

Comment: Install firebug or other good javascript debugging aid, your script throws on the first line of callback.

Comment: already using firebug - didn't like it. i mostly use colorbox plugin, which brings another iframed window, so when content changes - firebug somehow closes all tags and brings me to the main window.